# размер резервной копии базы данных 0 байтов(size of file after pg_dump = 0 bytes)

Tags: python, postgresql, резервное-копирование, dump, pgadmin4

Мне надо сделать резервную копию базы данных на postgresql, я попыталась использовать pg_dump)
вот мой код:

```
BACKUP_PATH = 'C:/python_project'
TIMESTAMP = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
BACKUP_FILE = DB_NAME + '_' + TIMESTAMP + '.sql'
BACKUP_CMD = "pg_dump -h {0} -p {1} -U {2} -d {3} > {4}".format(DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_NAME, os.path.join(BACKUP_PATH, BACKUP_FILE))
os.system(BACKUP_CMD)
```

после запуска, у меня появляется новый sql файл который по сути и является копией, проблема в том, что в него ничего не записалось и размер соответственно равен 0 байтов.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Для начала я порекомендовал бы для указания выходного файла вместо оператора перенаправления вывода ОС `>` воспользоваться параметром самого pg_dump `-f`.

Из встроенных в PostgreSQL средств для резервного копирования БД принято использовать утилиту `pg_basebackup`. Утилита `pg_dump` - для снятия дампов, а не для резервного копирования.

Comment: @Rabban Keyak, спасибо за совет, но у меня вопрос, нигде не могу найти, как установить pg_basebackup. я сделала всё как Вы сказали, но размер всё еще 0 байтов, хоть ошибки и нет, но я думаю проблема в том, что не получается найти эту функцию

Comment: Если вернуться к вопросу запуска именно `pg_dump`, то, если его вызов из python создаёт файл размером 0 байт, то следует попробовать вызвать команду вручную из командной оболочки (bash или cmd.exe), чтобы увидеть, не происходит ли при этом какой-либо ошибки. С высокой вероятностью ошибка есть, но я не вижу в вашем коде на python никакой её обработки или хотя бы вывода. Именно поэтому следует проверить команду вручную (или добавить вывод ошибки в код на python, с чем лично я помочь не могу).

Comment: Что касается `pg_basebackup`, то он входит в комплект поставки PostgreSQL. Соответственно, если у вас на машине уже стоит PostgreSQL server, то pg_basebackup находится в каталоге с бинарными файлами PostgreSQL. В свою очередь, расположение этого каталога зависит от того, какую ОС вы используете. Как и сама процедура установки PostgreSQL.
Если у вас Windows и вы устанавливали себе PostgreSQL сервер, то можно например найти ярлык оболочки psql и в его свойствах посмотреть путь расположения программы.

Comment: в итоге ни один из выше перечисленных способов не помог, сама искала через debian проблему, если в далеком будущем моим сомученникам понадобиться решение, смело пишите, скину и поясню